# How can I create VB.NET project for .net 7 in VS 2022

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

From what I've read we can still use VB.NET in .Net 7 but I don't see the option in VS 2022 to create a project

[image: Image Link. Image embed not yet allowed for my account]

All of these project can only be created for .net framework. Am I missing any package/feature that needs to be installed.

I can create .net 7 project when using C#

Comment: One can open a cmd window and type `dotnet new list` or `dotnet new list | find /i "VB"` to see what templates exist for VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .net core project in vb.net for desktop.

So, quite much "anything" without .net "framework" means .net core.

The above applies both vb.net, and c#.

So, for example, to create a desktop (winforms) application, you see 2 choices for vb.net.

eg these two:

[image]

And this one:

[image]

So, the choice WITHOUT .net "framework" means .net core.

so, then this:

[image]

HOWEVER!!!!!!

There are ZERO choices for web based vb.net choices and .net core.

So,

Desktop: Yes - .net core is a choice for vb.net

Web:  NO, .net core is NOT a a choice for vb.net

So, you can't choose vb.net + .net core for web based, only for desktop.

In a summary, this means if you going to do .net core web development, then you HAVE to choose c#, and no such choice exists for vb.net.

So, while vb.net can be .net core, ONLY for desktop.

You can create asp.net web sites in vb.net, and you can create webforms projects, and you can also choose MVC (again web based) projects in vb.net.

However no choice for .net core, and thus no blazer web choices (web assembly) can be had right now with vb.net.